# What message validations are possible with the package Rebus.MessageValidation?

Tags: rebus

There is a package: https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.MessageValidation
Judging by the source it only two extension methods. One empty method "EnableMessageValidation" and the second a static method "Batch" with splitting of the enumeration.

In the tests package contains:

```
Configure.With(activator)
    .Transport(t => t.UseInMemoryTransport(new InMemNetwork(), "validation-check"))
    .Options(o => o.EnableMessageValidation())
    .Start();
```

Tell me, please, what message validations are possible with the package Rebus.Message Validation? If any then how to add my verification code?

Comment: The library is supposed to wire up [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) such that incoming and outgoing messages are validated. It' awaiting a PR from the dude who proposed the project though, so it's not currently in a functional state.

Comment: Wire up FluentValidation that would be great! I am using FluentValidation together with the Mediator to validate commands in the internal logic of the domain. It would be great to have the same means of validation and to integration events, transmitted through Rebus. I will monitor the development of this package.